# Parse response of type AnyObject into Codable model

Tags: json, swift, alamofire, codable

I have started on someone's project having difficulties in parsing the response into Codable model. Below is the code snippet, which returns me **resultData as AnyObject**

```
switch response.result {
    case .success(let resultData):
      taskCallback(1, resultData as AnyObject)
    case .failure(let error):
      print(error) 
  }
```

I have been trying to parse the response into Codable model but it requires me AnyObject of type Data. How do I convert AnyObject into type Data.

```
let model = try JSONDecoder().decode([SomeModel].self, from: resultData)
```

I can't alter the completion handler response as its being used at so many places

[Here is the screenshot of printed response of responseObject]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6RRM.png

Comment: An answer depends strongly on the type of `response`. Alamofire 5 and higher supports `Codable` directly. And `SwiftyJSON` is outdated and should no be used anymore.

Answer (score 0):

`JSON` is almost certainly a wrapper around [JSONSerialization](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsjsonserialization?language=objc) (there is no stdlib or Foundation type called "JSON"). So if you want to turn that into Data, you would use JSONSerialization again. For example:

```
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: resultData)
```

This is of course very inefficient (you're decoding the JSON, re-encoding it, and the decoding it a second time), but it may be a stop-gap measure as you refactor to get rid of the AnyObject and use Decodable for the initial decoding.